# How to create a diff of two complex data structures?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

#### Problem specification:

I am currently searching for a elegant and/but efficient solution to a problem that i guess is quite common. Consider the following situation:

I defined a fileformat based on a [BTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btree) that is defined (in a simplified way) like this:

```
data FileTree = FileNode [Key] [FileOffset]
              | FileLeaf [Key] [Data]
```

Reading and writing this from a file to a lazy data structure is implemented and works just fine. This will result in a instance of:

```
data MemTree = MemNode [Key] [MemTree]
             | MemLeaf [Key] [Data]
```

Now my goal is to have a generic function `updateFile :: FilePath -> (MemTree -> MemTree) -> IO ()` that will read in the `FileTree` and convert it into a MemTree, apply the `MemTree -> MemTree` function and write back the changes to the tree structure. The problem is that the FileOffsets have to be conserved somehow.

I have two approaches to this problem. Both of them lack in elegance and/or efficiency:

#### Approach 1: Extend MemTree to contain the offsets

This approach extends the MemTree to contain the offsets:

```
data MemTree = MemNode [Key] [(MemTree, Maybe FileOffset)]
             | MemNode [Key] [Data]
```

The read function would then read in the `FileTree` and stores the `FileOffset` alongside the `MemTree` reference. Writing will checks if a reference already has an associated offset and if it does it just uses it.

*Pros*: easy to implement, no overhead to find the offset

*Cons*: exposes internal to the *user* who is responsible to set the offset to `Nothing`

#### Approach 2: Store offsets in a secondary structure

Another way to attack this problem is to read in the `FileTree` and create a `StableName.Map` that holds onto the `FileOffsets`. That way (and if i understand the semantics of `StableName` correctly) it should be possible to take the final `MemTree` and lookup the `StableName` of each node in the the `StableName.Map`. If there is an entry the node is clean and doesn't have to be written again.

*Pros*: doesn't expose the internals to the user

*Cons*: involves overhead for lookups in the map

#### Conclusion

These are the two approaches i can think of. The first one should be more efficient, the second one is more *pleasant to the eye*. I'd like your comments on my ideas, maybe someone even has a better approach in mind?

#### [Edit] Reasonal

There are two reasons i am searching for a solution like this:

On the one hand you should try to handle errors before they arise by using the type system. The aforementioned *user* is of course the designer of the next layer in the system (ie me). By working on the pure tree representation some kinds of bugs won't be able to happen. All changes to the tree in the file should be in one place. That should make reasoning easier.

On the other hand i could just implement something like `insert :: FilePath -> Key -> Value -> IO ()` and be done with it. But then i'll lose a very nice trait that comes free when i keep a (kind of a) log by updating the tree in place. Transactions (ie merging of several inserts) are just a matter of working on the same tree in memory and writing just the differences back to the file.

Comment: Why are you exposing the `MemTree` type to the user?  Can't you keep the internals private, and expose whatever interface you want?

Comment: Not really a proper solution, but this question prompted a bit of tinkering with type-enforced versions of your first approach, i.e. where the user must handle things (but gets a compiler error if they don't). [Some rough code on hpaste](http://hpaste.org/76248) if you're curious. Ended up going off in a slightly different direction though, so probably doesn't help you in this case.

Comment: I think @pat is right - hide the structure and provide functions to manipulate and traverse the tree, but implement the reference plumbing and file updating behind the scenes. I think the offsets are more use for labelling nodes than `StableName`s. Note also that there's an issue that your tree might end up being a circular graph [e.g. by tying the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) or through more innocent copying of the root node; using the original offsets can help you spot loops, careful interface design could prevent them. Avoid saving an infinite tree in your file!

Comment: I can see what @pat's point is and added a short reasonal to the question.

Comment: The right interface depends on what responsibilities the user has.  Is the user or library responsible for memory management of the file contents?  For instance, who decides whether to relocate file nodes when the user modifies them?  What happens if the user duplicates or removes `MemTree` nodes?

Comment: @Heatsink That's exactly the thing. User actions (eg insert or delete) may modify the `MemTrees` structure. If there is a way to find the difference between the old tree and the new only the necessary changes need to be written to the file. (Memory managment is of course not a responsibility for the user.)

Comment: You can keep all your updating at the pure MemTree level, certainly - that's good for the reasons you said. Pure code is excellent. That doesn't stop you hiding the details of MemTree and insisting the user uses a functional interface. You could expose pattern guards if you think pattern matching is crucial to your users, but I'd avoid it. Your insert function shouldn't mention FilePath or IO, just MemTree, but should secretly update the Maybe FileOffset data that you're hiding fronm the user, then you can have a completely separate updateFile function, as per your original plan.

Comment: @AndrewC: maybe you are right. I guess i am trying to overengineer a trivial problem. I was hoping that there is a *cool* solution for hiding the additional information per node. Some way like the State Monad 'hides' the state when it is not needed. That way the type system would prevent me from making stupid mistakes. But if there is  no way of achieving this i'll go with the *simple* way.

Comment: Monads can hide stuff because they use a standard interface (and syntax) that do all the plumbing under the hood. You can hide the additional information with a monad, but perhaps that's not the best interface to a tree! Why not roll your own interface that hides the plumbing under the hood? Maybe have a public `MemTree` and private `MemTreeAnnotated`. `insert` should secretly add `Nothing` for the FileOffset, `leftSubTree` and `rightSubTree` should give you the data without the FileOffset annotations, but `fmap` could preserve it if FileOffset counts in nodes. `delete` should preserve it.

Comment: BTW, I don't think this counts as over-engineering, it counts as seperating pure code from IO code, which is _really_ good practice.

Comment: @Florian: The closest equivalent to how `State` works would probably be requiring the user to construct a reified update function, zipper-style, instead of exposing `MemTree` directly. If the user has the `MemTree` constructors, tedious structural equality checks are about the best you can do. The stuff in the hpaste above (which would certainly be insanely overengineered) really amounts to a shortcut for that, by marking subtrees that are unchanged and thus don't need to be checked further.

Comment: @C.A.McCann thanks for the `Zipper` reference. I wasn't aware of that idiom.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the package [Data.Generic.Diff](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gdiff-1.1/docs/Data-Generic-Diff.html) may do exactly what you wanted. It references somebody's thesis for the idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am very new at Haskell so I won't be showing code, but hopefully my explanation may help for a solution.

First, why not just expose only the MemTree to the user, since that is what they will update, and the FileTree can be kept completely hidden.  That way, later, if you want to change this to be going to a database, for example, the user doesn't see any difference.

So, since the FileTree is hidden, why not just read it in when you are going to update, then you have the offsets, so do the update, and close the file again.

One problem with keeping the offsets is that it prevents another program from making any changes to the file, and in your case that may be fine, but I think as a general rule it is a bad design.

The main change, that I see, is that the MemTree shouldn't be lazy, since the file won't be staying open.